# Wordpress: Redirect Old to New Permalink Structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

My sites old permalink structure was **example.com/%postname%**

Now, I changed my all posts permalink to new structure **example.com/people/%postname%**

Problem is that old permalinks not redirecting to the new structure. I tried "redirection" plugin but it does not work.

Is there any plugin or htaccess code to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yoast provides a free tool which will allow you to generate the code for the .htaccess file, you can find it [here](https://yoast.com/research/permalink-helper.php) and the associated [blog post](https://yoast.com/change-wordpress-permalink-structure/)

This should do what you are asking

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1
```